# how can I extends from another class

Tags: python, django

I'm new in Python/Django and I'm working on a little project to improve my self, I would like to know how can I extends or how can I call a function from another class I already tried but I got some errors

this is my code :
first class

```
# Create your views here.
class ContactCenter(object):
    def myFunction(self, logged_user_id = None):
         print("hello")
```

second class

```
from apps.contact.views import ContactCenter

class ListModelMixin(object):

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ContactCenter.myFunction()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in two ways, one subclass if from `ContactCenter`:

```
class ListModelMixin(ContactCenter):

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.myFunction()
```

Or call the function from an instance of `ContactCenter`:

```
class ListModelMixin(object):

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = ContactCenter()
        instance.myFunction()
```

Comment: i used the first way, but i got an error  :    type object 'ContactCenter' has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: It should not have any attribute objects. Can you please add the code you were trying to run in the question with error stacktrace please?